# How to stabilize frame rates in GoogleARCore /Augmented face app

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, face

Currently I am making Augmented Face application
In this application ı have a slight problem
My camera FPS rate is between 20-25 how can i make it 30 fps stable?
İ am using S9+
I disabled everything even scene is empty but when arcore session starts it drops to 15 - 25 fps.
I am using Unity 2019

Comment: What is your video resolution?

Comment: 16:9 QHD 2560x1440

Comment: That's simply too much for your CPU. I believe that you can get 30 FPS for 1080p.

Comment: I will take a look thank you.